# Forces App to run in zoom to fill compatibility mode for tablets

Tags: android-layout, android

I am creating an app with min SDK version = 7. Due to the limitation with the app, for SDK version 11 or above, I do not want tablet-size devices to have the option to stretch to fill screen so I want to force it to run under compatibility mode for all these x-large screens. I tried to read the doc but I am still a little confused on how to always enforce compatibility mode so that it will always zoom to fill screen without presenting the user with an option to choose. Here is the relevant portion of my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mytest.HelloWorld"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"/>
```

Am I doing this correctly for my SDK version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These attributes (uses-sdk and supports-screens) only influence Android Market, not the runtime behaviour of a device. You should include a layout targeted at tablets: layout-xlarge, then there won't be any compatibility mode needed and not zoom options presented to the user. Look at [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DensityConsiderations) in the docs, it describes very nicely what sizes are supported and how to target them: tablets are "extra large".